# Probability hit "bullseye"

Tags: calculus, probability

I have to finish en example, but don't know how to do it.

We hahve a shooting target. [image]
Let's say that distribution in this target is bivariate normal distribution (x,y). [image: Sigma(x) and sigma(y) are 0]. We have this formula for probability density:
[image]

The center of the target is [image: (0,0)]. The points (x,y) will have polar coordinate:
[image]

Probability density f(x,y) is:[image]

I need to calculate the (integral) probability hit on "bullseye" if we have r=1 for the last formula.
Can anyone know how to do it?

Comment: @Walls You beat me by 5 seconds! Ah! :P

Comment: Ok. I will move there. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to integrate

$$P = \int\limits_0^R {\frac {rdr}{2π \sigma^2}} e^{\frac{-(r/\sigma)^2}{2}}$$

The derivative of

$$e^{\frac{-(r/\sigma)^2}{2}}$$
is

$$-\frac{r}{\sigma^2} \cdot e^{\frac{-(r/\sigma)^2}{2}}$$

So the integral of

$$\frac{r}{2π \sigma^2} e^{\frac{-(r/\sigma)^2}{2}}$$

is

$$-\frac{e^{\frac{-(r/\sigma)^2}{2}}} {2\pi}$$

which is easy enough to evaluate at $R$ and $0$.

**EDIT:**

To review, if

$$f(r)=\frac{d}{dr}g(r)$$

then

$$\int\limits_a^b {f(r)}dr  = g(b)-g(a)$$

In this case

$$\frac{r}{2π \sigma^2} e^{\frac{-(r/\sigma)^2}{2}} = \frac{d}{dr}\left(-\frac{e^{\frac{-(r/\sigma)^2}{2}}} {2\pi}\right) = \frac{-1}{2\pi}\frac{d}{dr}\left({e^{\frac{-(r/\sigma)^2}{2}}}\right)$$

so

$$P = \int\limits_0^1\frac{r dr}{2π \sigma^2} e^{\frac{-(r/\sigma)^2}{2}} = \frac{-1}{2\pi}\left({e^{\frac{-(1/\sigma)^2}{2}}}-{e^{\frac{-(0/\sigma)^2}{2}}}\right)$$

$$= \frac{-1}{2\pi}\left({e^{\frac{-(1/\sigma)^2}{2}}}-1\right)$$

$$= \frac{1}{2\pi}\left(1-{e^{\frac{-(1/\sigma)^2}{2}}}\right)$$

Comment: @Harold: Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. But still have problems. I did learn 10 years ago (just basic integrals and derivates) and i forgot how to calculate this.

Comment: @LikeMike: which step is giving you trouble?

Comment: Is there just enough to put value for r=1 in the $$-\frac{e^{\frac{-(r/\sigma)^2}{2}}} {2\pi}$$ and get result?

Comment: if sigma is 0 does that mean the chance is zero?

Comment: @ldgorman: Yes. In that case the archer's aim is so bad that the arrow could land as easily anywhere on the plane, so the chance of hitting within an inch of the bullseye -- or within a gigaparsec of the bullseye -- is basically zero.